# When it is clear to me that you are lying

Tags: idioms

Imagine someone is lying you and you are aware about the truth behind his / her sayings. suddenly when they are explaining their tales, you cannot control yourself and laugh. They ask you about the reason why you laughed. Not considering if they will be upset or not, you want to let them know that "it was clear that they were lying".

There is an idiom in my language which says:

It is like a painting that you are lying. [Meaning that everything has been visible to you because the way they were lying was not the way one could believe it.]

In a translation book I read the following sentences:

> - It stands out a mile that you are lying.
> - It sticks out a mile that you are lying.

But whereas it's author was a non-native individual, I doubt if they are direct translations from my language to English.

I need to know if an American person would say such a thing? If not is there any substitution for it in English?

Comment: Could they be a [pathological liar?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_lying) Sometimes they know they are lying, something they can't help lying, and sometimes they may even believe their own lies -- especially if they've told the lie often enough.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+sticks+out+a+mile%2CIt+stands+out+a+mile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20sticks%20out%20a%20mile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20stands%20out%20a%20mile%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the meaning is clear, but the phrasing does not sound native.

I would try some comparable idioms:

> That is a bald-faced lie. / That is a barefaced lie

(both of the above are acceptable, there's some argument as to which is the "original" phrasing)

If you're trying to point out how obvious it is you could try

> It's as plain as the nose on your face that you're lying.

Comment: I always thought that bare-faced lie implied that the liar was lying without shame, rather than that they were obviously lying.

Comment: I'm trying to get the exact context that the OP was using. Their example seemed to indicate a laughably obvious lie, which I think is covered by that idiom

Comment: This may be of related interest: [*“Bald Faced Lie” vs. “Bold Faced Lie”*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137551/bald-faced-lie-vs-bold-faced-lie). Growing up I only "understood" *bold faced lie*, even in this context.

Answer (score 0):

> Oldest trick in the book

A lie (or trick) that has been used so many times before that it is very well known.